# neo4j, how to exclude some path in all shortest path algorithm

Tags: neo4j, path-finding

I have a sort of city map where nodes are crosses and arcs are streets. I add an attribute "obstacle" at some streets almost randomly. Now I want to find some path from a point to another without having in this path any streets with this attribute. Is it possible?

This is the code I write and the problem is in the clause "street.obstacle is not null"

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((source:Cross)-[street:Street*]->(destination: Cross))
WHERE source.id="49" AND destination.id="57" AND 
      street.obstacle IS NOT NULL
return path AS shortestPath, 
       reduce(LENGTH=0, n IN rels(path)| LENGTH + n.length) AS totalLength
```

Comment: As @frobberofbits says `has` or `exists` but you could also try NOT(street.obstacle IS NULL).

Comment: i'd use not `has(street.obstacle)`

Answer (score 2):

Null doesn't apply to some boolean conditions.  [Read more in the docs here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-working-with-null.html#_introduction_to_null_in_cypher).   The expression `(NOT NULL)` returns `NULL`, not `false`, because null is treated as a third option, neither true nor false.  It's the absence of data really.

You might be looking for `has(street.obstacle)` instead, or possibly the `EXISTS()` function, depending on what you're trying to express.  Has will tell you whether the property exists (regardless of what value it has).

Comment: yes, I look at that before and the value of obstacle is not important. By the way, has(street.obstacle) doesn't work because street is not only one. I try to explain better. I have a - [ r ] -> b and r is a path that is composed by crosses(nodes) and streets (edges). How can i find that there isn't any street with the attribute obstacle?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I'm wondering in matter of performance what would be the difference of filtering the paths in upfront with a WHERE clause or just letting allShortestPaths doing his job and filtering the result with FILTER. It is on my to-do list for testing :)

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen by using the `PROFILE` keyword, you can discover the answer to that by trying it both ways.   http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/07/understanding-how-neo4j-cypher-queries.html

Comment: Yes I know how to profile, just wanted to say that you gave me the desire to do the tests for curiosity ;-)

Comment: I had read this article some while ago, still always a good read

Comment: I would hope that as the query optimizer gets better, it wouldn't matter which order you do things in, since as they're hopefully interchangable, you'd want a query optimizer that's smart enough to do the right thing and make the better choice based on selectivity.